# Is it possible to stream live video (IP camera) using asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, streaming, camera

I want to display videos of nearly 1000 cameras of the company I work for on the company's map, click the icon, and stream the live camera image in a popup.

But I couldn't find a resource that would work for us on the net.

Is it possible to do such a thing? Do you know a plugin that will work for me?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the cameras and their video feeds:

- **Option 1**: If all camera feeds are accessible directly from the client PC’s web browser.

This is the case, for example, if the client PC is inside your company’s network, and all cameras are inside the same network, and all the camera’s locations on the map are known, and all their URLs are known, etc.
For this case, you could associate the location on the map with the correct camera, and when the user clicks the map location, display the video using the corresponding camera’s URL.
This will only work if the cameras are broadcasting using a web-friendly video format, which many IP cameras support these days.

- **Option 2**: If the camera feeds are accessible to a central web server, but not directly to the client PCs. **Or** if the IP camera feeds are not all web-friendly.

If that’s the case, you will need a way to re-stream the video from the IP cameras to the client PC through the server.

For the **first option**, you can create your own code to associate the locations on the map with the different IP camera URLs. I think you could use the `<img>` and `<map>` HTML tags for this.

For the **second option**, you will need a server-side component that can receive from the IP cameras and re-stream the video from the server to the client PC browser. The company I work for has such components in the [LEADTOOLS multimedia SDK and streaming module](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/streaming). The exact component you’ll need depends in your configuration and use case, so I recommend downloading the free evaluation edition and contacting the LEAD support team with full details about what you’re trying to do. Support is free during the evaluation period.

Comment: My guess is the first option will do my job. All cameras and client are in the same network. I managed to run with VLC Activex Plugin in IE browser by embedding embed tag in html. But I have 2 big problems. The first is the delay in VLC, the second I saw that Mozilla and Chrome do not support. Am I right about these problems or am I missing something?

Comment: ActiveX is not supported by most modern browsers. If the IP camera format was "web-friendly", it doesn't need a plug-in. It can be played back by any modern browser that supports HTML5 (almost any browser updated in the past few years). If the camera's video feed URL doesn't work with the browser directly and needs a "plug-in", it might be better is to re-stream it in a web-friendly format than to install plug-ins on client machines.

Comment: I have3 different camera models. JVC,LG and HikVision.The user interfaces of these3 different cameras are not supported by chrome and mozilla and it wants me to install a plugin.I can only acquire images in IE.Normally, the cameras have interfaces soit's easy to open and look for a known camera.However, when there is a need to look at the camera of a location,it is necessary to find a camera on the location map.It is easier to find a camera by marking the locations of the cameras on all location maps on the web.I think it will bedifficult on the web.I decided to make the project a desktop app.

Comment: It might be worth it to try the evaluation I mentioned even with a desktop application. The SDK contains play-back and recording controls that can work with almost any type of video stream and they work with .NET WinForms (and also with C/C++ applications). If the evaluation doesn’t help you with your project, you can simply un-install it.

Comment: I don't want to use paid software. I will try to do it for free.